# Negative product containing vector and covariance matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm implementing the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) to measure the distance between two vectors of the same pool and just recognized that it seems to be correct the most but sometimes not, maybe due to negative values..
I realized that sometimes for

> [image: formula]

negative values occur. That's why the distance gets negative respectively the code throws up an error because root of a negative value..
I wonder about the problem. The data is (a row represents an object):

```
A: 376.498943729227 2.75082585760394    376.688899264061    2.75084113940164
B: 373.287817831307 2.75074375125675    373.392663499518    2.75092754974534
C: 377.091938091279 2.75082292557743    377.466035993347    2.75077191984784
D: 374.799551607287 2.75094834987157    374.209110037364    2.75091796001419
```

The covariance matrix S is then

```
7.13457e-09  3.13933e-05  5.45925e-10  3.80508e-06
 3.13933e-05      2.96355 -0.000115865      3.28797
 5.45925e-10 -0.000115865  5.31665e-09 -0.000137211
 3.80508e-06      3.28797 -0.000137211      3.79042
```

and the inverse of it is

```
 3.24779e+22 -8.58499e+18  1.40166e+22  7.92177e+18
-8.58499e+18   2.2693e+15 -3.70505e+18 -2.09399e+15
 1.40166e+22 -3.70505e+18  6.04917e+21  3.41882e+18
 7.92177e+18 -2.09399e+15  3.41882e+18  1.93222e+15
```

Now I wonder why I get negative results out of the highlighted product (in case of B and D)?
I'm not sure if its a programming problem (that's why I didn't include code lines, yet) or rather a theoretical one but I appreciate any help a lot!

I use the Eigen class.

**edit:**
I calculated the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix S via `R` and get:

> 7.593311e+02  1.243531e-01  1.156646e-02 -3.920936e-04

Why do I have different ones?
I used

```
M<- matrix(c(376.498943729227, 2.75082585760394, 376.688899264061, 2.75084113940164, 
       373.287817831307,    2.75074375125675,   373.392663499518,   2.75092754974534,
       377.091938091279,    2.75082292557743,   377.466035993347,   2.75077191984784,
       374.799551607287,    2.75094834987157,   374.209110037364,   2.75091796001419
       ), 4, 4)
> M
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 376.498944 373.287818 377.091938 374.799552
[2,]   2.750826   2.750744   2.750823   2.750948
[3,] 376.688899 373.392663 377.466036 374.209110
[4,]   2.750841   2.750928   2.750772   2.750918
ev<- eigen(M)
values<- ev$values
values
[1]  7.593311e+02  1.243531e-01  1.156646e-02 -3.920936e-04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your covariance matrix has two eigenvalues that are almost zero (10^-10 and 10^-18). Therefore, the matrix cannot be easily inverted, it might even be considered as non-invertible.

The reason for the two small eigenvalues is that your data points do not fill the entire 4D space but only a 2D subspace (a plane embedded in 4D).

To calculate a reasonable distance, you need to project your points onto a 2D space (or whatever dimensionality your real data have). You can do this with PCA. After this, you can calculate the distance in 2D.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response! I know only a bit of PCA but when I apply it I can use the above distance to measure vectors with four properties?

Comment: Yes. As long as you are only removing the dimensions with no data (i.e. small eigenvalues), you are preserving the distance. The essential point is that your four properties are not independent.

Comment: Thanks again! Can I prevent issues when I take larger sample data? Or will the problem remain?

Comment: If the larger sample set is a real 4D set, then yes.

Comment: Mh, do you know how is correlation connected with the sample size?

Comment: I tried it with the complete sample I have (~ 1000) and indeed, no error occured. Where is the threshold that I can use it?
Nevertheless, I will have a look at PCA, I guess, it's then sample-independent?

Comment: There is no threshold on the number of data points. There can be a data set with four points with independent properties. But they might also be dependent. It is simply a matter of distribution. For example, consider 3D space. If the points are distributed in a sphere, you are good because they span the entire 3D space. On the other hand, if they are only distributed on a plane, you are essentially missing one dimension.

Comment: I understand, thank you! And when I apply PCA I can circumvent this issue (I'm already trying to realize it with libpca)?

Answer (score 2):

I copy&pasted your matrix to Matlab and computed eigenvalues, and the smallest of them is `-4.0819e-13`.

Which doesn't seem that bad, but it shows a problem. A covariance matrix should be positive semidefinite, and therefore no eigenvalue should be smaller than `0`. Likely due to rounding issues in your code, the matrix has a (slightly) negative eigenvalue, which can result in a problem like you are having.

Also, since two of the eigenvalues are practically zero, computing the inverse is a very brave move indeed. Meaning: you shouldn't, since you are essentially computing the inverse of a singular matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What might be a remedy? Do I have to cut the number after a few digits?